# How do I disable a button in a form?

Tags: angular

I want the signup button to be disabled whenever the form is complete.

```
<form [formGroup]="service.formModelInstrumexts" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()"
  style="background-color: #0067b8 !important; margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 600px; margin-right: 600px;">
  <div style="padding: 15px">

<div>
  <h3 style="color: azure">
    اضافه کردن ساز
  </h3>
</div>
    <select   id="ddl" style="width:200px; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 0px;" dir="rtl"
      class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
      <option> لطفا نوع ساز را انتخاب نمایید</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of type; let i = index" style="color: black;" (click)="test(item.id)" >{{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>نام</label>
      <input style="width: 40%; margin-left: 60%; border-radius: 0px;" class="form-control" formControlName="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>توضیحات</label>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="name"  style="direction: rtl; color: rgb(3, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px;" class="form-control" formControlName="Comment"
        aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
    </div>


    <div  *ngIf="name != null" >
      <app-upload style=" width: 100px; "
        (onUploadFinished)="uploadFinished($event)"></app-upload>
      <img src="http://localhost:54277/{{this.response.dbPath}}" *ngIf="this.response.dbPath != null" width="200px"
        height="200px">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <button style="width: 100px; color: #0067b8; background-color: #fff; border-color: transparent; border-radius: 0px;margin-left: 8px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block"
          [disabled]="!service.formModelInstrumexts.valid" >ثبت
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit button will be dependent on form Validity.

```
[disabled]= "!service.formModelInstrumexts.valid"
```

Another way would be template reference variables

```
<form #myForm [formGroup]="service.formModelInstrumexts"  (submit)="onSubmit()">
```

then

```
[disabled]= "!myForm.valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth to mention is case when you want to disable eg. input with directive `formControl` or `formControlName`, then Angular then inform you about it as warning in console:

> ```
>   It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
>   when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>   you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

Another approach would be to disable/enable certain button or control inside ts code:

```
form: FormGroup;

this.form = new FormGroup({
  someControl: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
  if (status === 'VALID') {
    this.form.controls.someControl.disable({emitEvent: false}); // Prevent circular status change notification
  } else {
    this.form.controls.someControl.enable({emitEvent: false}); // Prevent circular status change notification
  }
});

setTimeout(() => this.form.controls.someControl.setValue('123'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => this.form.controls.someControl.setValue(''), 2000);
```